# Why do the Narns get their own seat on the council?

Tags: babylon-5

At the start of the *Babylon 5* series, the Council of Babylon 5 consists of five main ambassadors - human, Minbari, Centauri, Narn, and Vorlon - and a bunch of misfits from the League of Non-Aligned Worlds, such as the Drazi, Pakmara, and so on.

The **humans** are clearly entitled to one of the primary seats on the council: they built Babylon 5 and set this whole thing up. So are the **Minbari**: co-sponsors of Babylon 5, and a civilisation easily powerful enough to destroy humanity. So are the **Centauri**: they might not be in their prime any more, but they're at least the remnants of a great empire, as well as the first aliens to form relations with humans. The **Vorlons** are, as usual, a total mystery, but at least they're undoubtedly powerful.

So where do the **Narns** come in? They were a Centauri colony until recently (within living memory). What makes them more important and powerful than, say, the Drazi - enough to merit one of the five main seats on the Council, rather than a place on the benches with the less powerful races?

Comment: I can't provide any references for this, but I got the impression the Narn were more aggressively colonial and expansionist than most of the league, either by intent or ability.  In technology they may not be much ahead of the Drazi, but they're pushing the envelope more, thus the seat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Military might, for one.**

The Narn have a mighty war machine in place.  They're constantly building weapons, or stealing them, or salvaging them, and when they're not using them, they're selling them.  The Drazi may love a good fight, and it's likely they're the strongest military within the League on that basis alone, but we never see battlecruiser level ships from them.

**It's a peaceful mission...**

... and the Narn-Centauri conflict is just about the biggest threat to peace that Earth can currently see, other than pissing off the Minbari again.  If the conflict goes hot, Earth would get drawn into one side or another, as Earth has been tentative allies and customers of both empires.  Ignoring that particular elephant - or provoking the conflict by ignoring one side - would be a disaster.

**Earth is just as young, and they're setting the table.**

The discovery of Earth by the Centauri dates to approximately the same time as the discovery of Narn by the Centauri.  Within that timeframe the Narn not only suffered Centauri occupation, but threw off that chain and proceeded to outbuild their former masters.  That would make them fairly similar to Earth, and Narn might have been even stronger, if they hadn't given up several opportunities to make allies, like Earth did with the Dilgar War.

Comment: "*If the conflict goes hot, Earth would get drawn into one side or another*" - but when the conflict DID go hot, Earth (and the other powers, barring you-know-who) refused to weigh in on either side, leaving the Narns to get hammered.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - at that point Earth had already had a "change of heart".  Via assassination of the leader that actually did care about keeping peace and B5's mission.  Or put it another way, I am assuming the pre-B5 Earth government actually gave a crap.

Comment: The Narn had also supplied weapons and ships to the Humans during the Human-Minbari war, so were on reasonably good terms when the Council was established

Comment: @HorusKol - everyone there (save the obvious exception) was there due to their ties to Earth, so I didn't really feel that was good evidence one way or the other.

Comment: Well, it seems to go someway to explain what separates the Narn (and other full council members) from the species the Non-Aligned worlds...

Comment: @HorusKol - the League had the Dilgar War, which probably gave them much stronger ties to Earth, who pulled their ass out of the fire, than the Narn playing friendly neighborhood arms dealer.  That said, the League were also a diverse and not-terribly-unified lot, or they would have held more sway.

Comment: The League were also their own group, rather than independent nations like the members of the council. When the Centauri reconquered the Narn, the Narn lost their seat on the council. Additionally, since the League was fairly fractious and noncommittal it's doubtful they could have chosen a single ambassador to represent all of them on the council.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me say that I like @Radhil's answer a lot and that he hits on some very solid points.  I think the primary reason the five governments were who they are shown, not from them, but from the name of the group containing everyone else.  The League of Non-Aligned Worlds.  This gives me the impression that the five "Major" governments are aligned. The question then becomes, how are they aligned, and to that, I fell the answer should be obvious. Babylon 5 itself. This group is called the "Babylon 5 Advisory Council." So, what makes the Narns important enough for a seat on the council? The fact that they were offered and/or asked to be part of the council.

To answer the other part of your question, about power, you are essentially correct that they are the youngest of the five council members. So how is it then that they are considered one of the major powers.  Ironically, the Centauri can be thanked for this.  When the Centauri first discovered the Narn, the Narn were an agrarian people with only a few colonies and very primitive spacecraft. Over the course of the next hundred years, the Centauri brutalized the Narn, but the Narn were able to study the Centauri technology either through observation as slaves or reverse engineering after theft. So, after fifty years of being free, the Narn were able to incorporate what they had learned from the Centauri into their own technology and made subsequent improvements. So, at the beginning of the show (2258), the Narn have been able to advance to the point where they are considered a major power in the galaxy.

Also, while I haven't been able to find concrete proof, from inferences from the dialogue I kind of assume that the Narns have been going through an expansionist phase and have a rather large territory at this point, more so than the members of the League. At least, that's my take on things.

Comment: "The League ... obvious. Babylon 5 itself." - I am not convinced of the assumptions here. The non-aligned worlds are not aligned ... to any of the "major" powers. I doubt this lets us conclude those majors powers are "aligned" to anything, other than to themselves. As is stated on [this B5 wiki](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/League_of_Non-Aligned_Worlds), "the League signed on to the Babylon Project". This sounds pretty much "aligned with B5" to me. And really, why should anyone *not* "aligned" with B5 be in the B5 advisory council in the first place?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper presumably the League is mostly slave races to the Dilgar empire.  So they have a loose alliance with each other and have a lot of gratitude to Earth for liberating them.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: [This wiki article](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Dilgar) says: "the Earth Alliance fought on the side of the League and battled the Dilgar, forcing them back to their homeworld. After the war ended, the Dilgar sun went supernova, effectively wiping out the entire species." Therefore, I very much doubt that, at the time of the B5 series, anyone is a slave race to the Dilgar Empire.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper obviously.  The point is that the Dilgar appears to be what League worlds have in common and their subsequent loose alliance.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a historical precenent for a situation where former colony (Narn) quickly ends up almost as strong as original colonizator (Centauri):

you can look at them **(Narns) as the United States in the 19th** century - they are a former colony of the vast and powerful **British Empire (i.e Centauri in this analogy)**, but they rebelled, threw British out and after a while, USA's power was comparable to the power of the British Empire and at the end of the 19th century, USA was definitely one of Earth's superpowers.

---

This is my speculation and I have no "inside information" on how this was developed.

Comment: This reminds me of [another related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/262977/31394) - if you have stronger evidence/proof that the UK and US were inspiration for the Centauri and Narn, then maybe it could make a good answer over there.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - that's not what I was saying - I wasn't suggesting that was the inspiration (it wouldn't make sense past the 19th century) - I was just showing, that former colony may be very powerful indeed and that there is historical precedent for that situation. I'll correct my answer, but if you think this is misleading, flag it and I'll delete it.

Comment: @JanSpurny: I do think it is slightly misleading, as "former colony" are two quite different things here. The Narn were former colony by occupation, meaning that they evolved to the civilization they had on their own, before the Centauri arrived and conquered them. The United States, in contrast, were a former colony by settlement, meaning that the settlers that would evolve into the independent society came (in part) from the British Empire in the first place. It may not render your point completely invalid, but I'm not sure how comparable the two cases are.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I aggree - no analogy is perfect. My point was it's not "unheard of". There's probably better analogy: Romans and Gauls - but I don't know enough history to be sure - I think the Gauls were conquered, then threw Romans out, and then Romans conquered them again, which is probably closer to Narn-Centauri "relationship". Also, I used USA vs British, because I thought most people (including me) are more familiar with recent history. But feel free to flag this or downvote - I myself am not sure it's a good answer and I'm fine with deleting it.