# Any acknowledged real-world inspiration for the Centauri - Narn conflict?

Tags: inspiration, babylon-5

One of the major plots of the *Babylon 5* series is the conflict between the Centauri (an ancient but declining empire) and the Narn (a rapidly industrialising former Centauri colony), represented on Babylon 5 by the ambassadors Londo Mollari and G'Kar, two of the greatest characters in TV sci-fi whose character arcs and relationship are one of the main highlights of the show.

Like many aspects of the Babylon 5 universe, the Centauri-Narn conflict can be seen as reminiscent of various things in real-world politics, while not being a 100% blatant reference to anything in particular.

**Has JMS, or others involved in the show, ever acknowledged specific source(s) of inspiration?** Either one real-world conflict that Centauri-Narn relations are broadly based on, or perhaps more than one real-world political relationship inspiring several different aspects of the fictional one. Or do they prefer to keep it neutral so that different watchers can find their own connections with different things, perhaps according to their own political viewpoints?

Comment: https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Babylon_5_influences

Comment: I've just re-watched B5 with my son, and the analogies to current real-world events are in some cases quite striking. The more things change, the more they stay the same...

Comment: The Centauri Empire is obviously based on the Roman Empire. The Narn were slaves of the Centauri, but rebelled and gained their freedom. The closest historical equivalent iss Spartacus' slave uprising, which, unlike the Narn rebellion, was beaten down in the end (though not easily). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartacus